# Table showing generic equivalents of C# 1 data types

Tags: c#, generics, reference

Some time ago I came across a table that listed the generic equivalents for C# 1 data types. This would be a handy reference to have around. Can anyone point me to this?

E.g., instead of Hashtable use ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[is this is it?](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Generics_Recipes%E2%80%94Replacing_the_Hashtable_with_Its_Generic_Counterpart)

[or I found this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx)

Which has this table

[table http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3601/tablemyr.jpg](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3601/tablemyr.jpg)

Comment: Incidentally I just used a hashtable. How 1.0 of me :)

Comment: That's it, thanks John! I googled for a while but mistakenly assumed it was too helpful for Microsoft to have provided ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ["When to Use Generic Collections"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172181.aspx)

Comment: That is a good article, but I was specifically looking for the mapping table.